# Use Android scaleGravity flags programmatically for ScaleDrawable constructor

Tags: android

### Problem:

How can I access the scaleGravity flag values programmatically?

### Situation:

I am using `ScaleDrawables` in a custom `View` class.
These `ScaleDrawables` need to have their `scaleGravity` set to center.

If I was inflating my `ScaleDrawables` from XML I would use `android:scaleGravity="center"`.

This sets the flag "center" which has the value 0x11 for the global attribute resource symbol [scaleGravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#scaleGravity).

I am however creating the `ScaleDrawables` dynamically, so I use the constructor which is of the form:

```
ScaleDrawable(Drawable drawable, int gravity, float scaleWidth, float scaleHeight)
```

The integer equivalent of the `scaleGravity` "center" flag value 0x11 is 17, so I can use:

```
ScaleDrawable scaleDrawable = new ScaleDrawable(sourceDrawable, 17, 1f, 1f);
```

Hard coding the value 17 isn't that good for readability though.
I could define constants for the custom `View` class:

```
private static final int CENTER = 17;
```

but this seems like unnecessary duplication.

So how can I get the flag values directly from `android.R.attr.scaleGravity` ?

Comment: Shouldnot the gravity parameter be something like Gravity.CENTER

Comment: Ahh... I'd assumed that since a lot of the constants in Gravity class are not valid for scaleGravity, that there would be something like a ScaleGravity class. But I guess that over complicates things. Thanks